# Create range(s) from single number

Tags: javascript

**SOLVED**
@Jeff and @Eric, thanks a lot. In the end I have to go with Eric's solution with a minor change.

```
for(; i+4<=n; i+=4)
```

This how I'm going to use it:

```
function findRange(n,div)
{
var odd =1&n;
var i = 0;
var ranges = [];

  for(; i + div<= n; i+=div) 
  {
     ranges.push([i+1, i+div]); // in array 1-4 / 5-8 etc
     // or in side cases the 2nd part of the array contains the remainder
     ranges.push([i+1, n]); // 1-16,5-16,9-16,etc
     ranges.push([i+div, n]); // 4-16,8-16,12-16,etc

     if(odd === 1)
     {
        ranges.push([i+div+1, n]); // in case of input 7 creates array 5-7
     }
  }

return ranges;
}
console.log(findRange(16,4));
```

### This solution answers the following questions

Question 1:
 How to create the ranges (1-4, 5-8, 9-12, 13-16) from f.e. the number 16

Question 4:
 How to find the 1st and last number from that range (1 and 4, 5 and 8 etc)

Question 2:
 How to deal with the situation where the input number is for example 17. This would give these ranges 1-4, 5-8, 9-12, 13-16 and a remaining number 17.

### Original question below.

I need to know how to create a range from a single number where the single number is variable. The range always needs to fall within 4 positions. Per range I need to know the first and last number. Per range I need to know the numbers in between.

For example: the single (input) number is 16, which gives the following 4 ranges of 4 (1-4, 5-8, 9-12, 13-16).

Question 1:
 How to create the ranges (1-4, 5-8, 9-12, 13-16) from f.e. the number 16

Question 2:
 How to deal with the situation where the input number is for example 17. This would give these ranges 1-4, 5-8, 9-12, 13-16 and a remaining number 17.

Question 3:
 How to deal with the situation where the input number is 3 so the range is 1-3

---

*Questions below are optional because these answers can probably be found here on stack.*

Question 4:
 How to find the 1st and last number from that range (1 and 4, 5 and 8 etc)

Question 5:
 How to find the numbers in the range (range1: 1,2,3,4 | range2: 5,6,7,8 etc) per range.

---

I haven't really tried anything yet because don't know how to get to the first step at all.

One thing I tried was using % (modulus) but that wasn't the answer. I tried this:

```
var x=16;

for(var i=0; i<=x; i++)
{
  for(i % 4 === 0)
  {
    return i;
  }
}
```

it gave me 4,8,12,16 which is nice but far from what I'm looking for. I'm very tired of breaking my head about this. I'm very curious what would be the solution for this.

I'm not sure if it's allowed to ask questions this way. But since they are all related to the range I thought it would be good to be as specific as possible about what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, I was going to answer it, but now it's closed, so I'ma put a comment here to hopefully help you. You need to grab the first and last part of each range in your loop - so something like `var output = []` outside, then inside the loop have `if(i%4 === 1) output[i/4] = {bottom:i}; if(i%4 === 0) output[i/4].top = i;` - that will get the top and bottom. As for dealing with the edge cases, you'll have to use more `if` statements with appropriate checks. edit: e.g. `if(i === x) output[i/4].top = i;`

Comment: @Jeff thx for responding even though it's closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
var ranges = [];
for(; i + 4< n; i+=4) ranges.push([i+1, i+4]);
ranges.push([i+1, n])
```

Comment: Jeff and Eric, thanks a lot. In the end I have to with Eric's solution with a minor change.

Comment: @Fluffy: did you try this with side cases?

Comment: thanks for mentioning this. After reading your comment I checked the arrays again and indeed with the side cases the 2nd part of the array contains the remainder. I will adjust my text!

Comment: there's something not clear when using nrs like 7, 15 I tried to solve it by checking if the input number is odd and if so add an extra array with the following number (see example). Not sure if it's the correct way though.